# preload sound with soundmanager2

Tags: soundmanager2

In using soundmanager 2 is there a way to pre-load a track if you know what is the next and previous track that will be played. This will of course quicken the load times for the user in switching between sounds. In the documentation there is a function `autoLoad()` and `load()` and I am not sure which one should be used to achieve pre-loading music.

I should also ask when is the best time to start the preload I was thinking during the `whileplaying()` function.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Any idea on how this should be done